# Spinner items not showing at first time

Tags: java, android

I have  activities- **StartupActivity** and **MainActivity**.

In StartupActivity i am inserting some data in a table and staring the MainActivity by using intent.

Code inside **StartupActivity** :

```
db.addFriend("userNameTest"); //db is a DataBase handler class and has been initialized inside onCreate()
Intent home = new Intent(StartUp.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(home);
finish();
```

Data is inserting successfully, as i can see them in the DB table. Also, MainActivity is starting properly.

Inside MainActivity i am retrieving the data from table and showing in a spinner.

Code inside onCreate method of **MainActivity** :

```
 List<String> list = db.getFriends();

 dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 friendSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 friendSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
                       { String frnd_name = (String)dataAdapter.getItem(position); }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {  }
            });
```

Spinner is not showing any data for the first time but if i press back button and than again navigate back to the activity it shows data in spinner. Plus, it only dosent show data when first run at installation time; after that for each run it shows data.

What can be the reason for this? Help me out please.

Another thing will be also helpful. if i add some data in the table and than try to refresh the dataAdapter of spinner or spinner itself. How am i going to do that? For now, i am just using the above code again; as i have tried dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();- which isn't working.

Comment: do this in onCreate -->  friendSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter); & in place of above line write adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

To:

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be like this because of getting that list from db might take while and your app can go directly to the next line of code which is where you declare your dataAdapter.

You can try using AsyncTask. Something like this should help;

```
`class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
     super.onPreExecute();
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
     pDialog.setMessage("Getting List...");
     pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
     pDialog.setCancelable(true);
     pDialog.show();
 }

 @Override
 protected List<String> doInBackground(String... args) {
     List<String> list = db.getFriends();

     ...

     return list;
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
     pDialog.dismiss();
     ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     friendSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 }
```

}`

And in the onCreate() method;

```
`GetList getList = new GetList();
 getList.execute();`
```

Hope this helps.